# How to make a video using raspberry pi camera without it crashing

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I have written a script using python (flask) which runs on local service

the scripts purpose is to create a video and store on my raspberry pi desktop which works

but after this video is created while a preview is shown, the camera crashes.

This is what I am trying below

```
import os
import os.path
from flask import Flask
from picamera import PiCamera
from time import sleep
import sys

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():

    camera = PiCamera()
    

    camera.start_preview()
    camera.start_recording('/home/pi/Desktop/play.h264')
    sleep(15)

   
    camera.stop_recording()
    camera.stop_preview()

  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=8000, host='0.0.0.0')
```

please see screenshot of error below

[image: preview of crash error returned]

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably need to use `with` to ensure the camera resources get properly released.

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    with PiCamera() as camera:
        # camera.start_preview()
        camera.start_recording('/home/pi/Desktop/play.h264')
        sleep(15)
        camera.stop_recording()
        # camera.stop_preview()
    return "OK"
```

If that doesn't help, there are some points about [the pi camera's hardware limits here](https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.13/fov.html#hardware-limits).

Comment: it actually does the recording but returns same error to my application page as the above which I did, maybe I need to add that I am accessing my flask url using window.localtion.href method, would you advice on abetter way to run my flask script so that this error is not returned to my main page

Comment: Does it work if you don't preview at the same time? You wouldn't see the preview anyway if you accessed the Flask app via somewhere else.

Comment: yes it worked without the preview, what if I tried using Ajax would it initiate the camera recording?

Comment: If you did an equivalent request using AJAX, yes, of course it would.

Comment: fantastic it works, the Ajax request did the trick please update ur answer with the Ajax request thingy incase some other person needs it

Comment: I'm not sure why an AJAX request would work differently here, but glad it works. I did edit in the fact that you need to return something from the view – maybe that was part of your problem.